# Restore windows from drive that failed to boot

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-backup

My ssd decided to stop booting. I tried windows repair from a USB boot drive without success. I did not want to reinstall windows on that drive, so I bought a second ssd and installed a fresh version of windows on it. I'm wondering what my options are at this point, is there a way to bring all my settings/programs from the "bad" SSD? Clone it but use the good, boot able new version of windows? I have a USB to SSD adapter so I can hook it up and see all my files.

I was pretty sure I was backing up my computer to my NAS. I have a folder in the Nas that has the old name of my computer with 2 folders inside: 'configuration' and 'data'. I tried to go to restore and select this folder and nothing.

I mainly want my office and windows activation code. I kept all my files on another sata drive. It would be nice to just have the new guy working like the old guy.

Thanks!

Comment: I would try cloning the old drive to the new one, this can be done with a boot disk made from your favorite cloning software. I use Macrium Reflect Free version. Install MRF on the new drive that has windows installed, then make the bootable rescue media, then boot from it and clone the old drive to the new one. See if the clone is successful by booting into the new cloned drive. There is no way to move programs and settings to a new Windows installation.

Comment: As @Moab mentions, you need to make a *drive image* (possibly compressed file with *all* SSD info) or a clone (*exact copy of the SSD*), rather than backing up just configuration files and data, to be sure the drive can be completely restored - there are hidden files and partitions that Backup leaves out. As mentioned, use third-party tools such as Reflect.

Comment: @Moab If I clone a drive that cannot boot wouldn't the new one not be able to boot?

Comment: Maybe, it is worth a try.